# Can random variables be conditioned in a cycle?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Given three random variables $A$, $B$, and $C$, can we in general reason about these if $P(A = a\mid B = b)$, $P(B = b\mid C = c)$, and $P(C = c\mid A = a)$ all (non-trivially) hold/are not equal to their unconditional counterparts? (I.e. $A$, $B$, and $C$ are conditional on each other in a cycle.)

If so, does this change if the three random variables are over disjoint, potentially binary/boolean outcome spaces?

If not, does it even make sense to write such relationships between conditional variables? Is there anything fundamental that stops us making such definitions?

Such reasoning seems difficult/infeasible in general as finding the probability of, say, $P(A=a)$, requires reasoning possibly (almost always?) to infinity.

A further, and generalised, question, which I assume has the same answer, is whether the conditionality of random variables must form a directed acyclic simple graph; relevant to my context of Bayesian networks.

Edit: As an example, consider three random variables (or possibly events?) $A$, $B$, and $C$ which are each binary. Suppose

- $P(A=T\mid B=T) = 0.1$ and $P(A=T\mid B=F) = 0$,
- $P(B=T\mid C=T) = 0.1$ and $P(B=T\mid C=F) = 0$, and
- $P(C=T\mid A=T) = 0.1$ and $P(C=T\mid A=F) = 0$.

It seems to me that actually $P(A=T)=0$ by some form of limit reasoning. But perhaps my question doesn't make sense?

Comment: What does $P(A\mid B)$ "holding" even mean?

Comment: $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B) / P(B)$ is well-defined whenever $P(B)>0$. Unclear what "holding" means.

Comment: @parsiad You're right but in the post $A$ and $B$ are said to be random variables, not events (raising the further question of what $P(A\mid B)$ means).

Comment: Also, even though I don't understand this question at all (as I've indicated) why have the cycle be in three variables? Why not a two variable cycle ($P(A\mid B)$ and $P(B\mid A)$) or even a one variable cycle ($P(A\mid A)$)? Shouldn't those have the same issue? (Whatever that issue is?)

Comment: I have editted the question to give an example. My question may not make sense; if so, please explain why.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen In the context I care about, those are not possible and they could be disallowed for other reasons that I didn't want to risk considering.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen This conditionality is as defined to be $P(Y=y|X=x) = P(X=x\cap Y=y)/P(X=x)$, as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution

Comment: For your edited question, it seems to me that you have events $A, B, C$ with  $P[A|B] = 0.1, P[A|B^c] = 0$, 
$P[B|C]=0.1, P[B|C^c]=0$, 
$P[C|A] = 0.1, P[C|A^c]=0$.
So then you can conclude $P[A]=0.1P[B]$ by the law of total probability, and so on, to indeed eventually prove $P[A]=P[B]=P[C]=0$. (Of course, in that case $P[A|B]$ is not really defined as it divides by 0).  So your example is not possible.

Comment: Indeed, and your reasoning includes a limit argument; is this valid in all cases? Perhaps such limits do not always converge.

Comment: @AlexW : What is your last comment referring to?  What limit?

Comment: Let us assume A,B,C are events.  Your initial statement ends up with P(A=T)=P(B=T)=P(C=T)=0.1.  You can get this situation by simply saying A=B=C, having a common probability of (T)=0.1, unless this is too trivial.

Comment: @Michael Your use of "eventually" suggested a limit. However, I suppose in this case one can determine $P[A] = 10^{-3}P[A]$ and conclude from there. But does this work for more complicated examples? It seems also feasible to fall into limits by going around the cycle in conditional limits infinitely. Whether my example is possible is what the example is indeed questioning.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Sure, but as my above comment stated, I was unsure whether that would impose additional problems and also it is not actually applicable to my situation for which this question will be useful, whereas my above example is. Also, I'm not sure why rephrasing the example important; are you saying that that example is valid, or invalid? That $P(A\mid A)=0.1$ is valid?

Comment: @AlexW Notice how you needed to write something like $P(A=a\mid B=b)$ rather than $P(A\mid B)$ to explain yourself? That's because without more context, it's hard to know what $P(A\mid B)$ means. You can actually sensibly condition on a random variable (or a closely related conditional an event involving a random variable $B=b$), but the probability of a random variable $A$ (as in $P(A\mid B)$) makes no sense whereas the probability of an event involving a random variable, (as in $P(A=a\mid B)$) does.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Okay, I think I follow. I was somewhat using $P(X\mid Y)$ as notational shorthand for $P(X=x\mid Y=y)$ to not include the specific value of the random variable. Should I change it to the latter of these two, does the former really not make sense? I want to ideally reason about random variables for my end-product so I used them to learn such information. My question is fundamentally identical and valid (to me) for events also, though.

Comment: @AlexW Yes, the notation $P(X=x\mid Y=y)$ in your example makes sense, while $P(X\mid Y)$ does not (keep in mind that at the outset we didn't even know that the RVs were binary). On the other hand, events and binary-valued RVs are close to the same thing, where you interpret the event as the binary variable taking some preferred one of its value, e.g. "true". I'm afraid I still don't much understand your question though, e.g. what it means for $P(A\mid B)$ to 'hold nontrivially'. Do you mean (where I'm using events) $P(A\mid B) \ne P(A),$ i.e. $P(B)\ne 0$ and $A$ and $B$ are not independent?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Noted, I did not realise this was not a reasonable shorthand, I'll edit it now. Yes that is what I mean; I tried to clarify but if you think you can edit the question to make it more clear that'd be appreciated.

Comment: @AlexW : By "eventually" I meant "after the process of applying the same reasoning two more times and concluding $P[A] = (0.1)^3 P[A]$."

Comment: @AlexW P(A|A) is identical with p9a0

Comment: @AlexW ignore previous comment

Comment: @AlexW  I think I've got an answer. Look at a Venn diagram with 3 overlapping disks, same radius, centers forming an equilateral triangle.  The entire diagram is within a large square (representing the entire probability space).  Each disk has a probability of 0.1 while the each of the intersections, of pairs of overlapping disks, has a probability of 0.01.  This picture gives what you want, with the disks representing A=T, B=T, and C=T.

Comment: @AlexW  My original comment (making the all the same) was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First, concretely about your example: The three probabilities on the right effectively say that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are logically equivalent. Interpreting $T$ as true and $F$ as false, we could write them as $\neg B\Rightarrow\neg A$, $\neg C\Rightarrow\neg B$ and $\neg A\Rightarrow\neg C$, respectively. Thus $A$, $B$ and $C$ are either all $F$ or all $T$. But then the probabilities on the left are all $1$ (or undefined, if they're never $T$), so the scenario you describe is impossible.

Now about your more general confusion: You seem to be thinking of conditional probabilities as something one-directional, inherently asymmetrical, something like causality perhaps. They're not, and thus there's no reason why they should be acyclic.

As an example, consider three coins that never all show the same side, whereas all $6$ results where they don't all show the same side are equiprobable. Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be the respective events that they show heads. Then

$$P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac12$$

whereas

$$
P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid C)=P(C\mid A)=\frac13\;.
$$

Or consider three switches of which exactly one is on, all with equal probability, and let $A$, $B$, $C$ be the respective events of the switches being on. Then

$$P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac13$$

whereas

$$
P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid C)=P(C\mid A)=0\;.
$$

(You said you weren't interested in only two variables or events, otherwise we'd even have had $P(A)=P(B)=\frac12$ with $P(A\mid B)=P(B\mid A)=0$ in both cases.)

There's nothing mysterious about this; in either case the three events are entirely symmetrical, they just happen to be dependent, and there's no reason why this dependence shouldn't result in all the conditional probabilities being different from their unconditional counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

After some clarification, you seem to be asking if it's possible for three events $A,B,C$ to be dependent on one another in a nontrivial way (i.e. none of the probabilities or conditional probabilities are zero or one.)

This is possible. For instance let $Z\in \{H,T\}$ be a fair coin toss, and then let $A$ $B$ and $C\in \{H,T\}$ be three independent coin tosses of a weighted coin whose weight is determined by $Z$: if $Z=H$, then probability of heads is $3/4,$ and if $Z=T,$ it is $1/4.$ It is clear by symmetry that we have $P(A=H)=P(B=H)=P(C=H)=1/2.$ But, it should also be clear from intuition that $P(A=H\mid B=H) > 1/2$ (since if $B=H$ it's more likely that the outcome of the first toss was $Z=H,$ and thus more likely that $A=H$), and similarly for all the other conditionals.

We can calculate all this as well. We have $$ P(A=H) = \frac{1}{2}P(A=H\mid Z=H) + \frac{1}{2}P(A=H\mid Z=T) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4} =\frac{1}{2} $$ as expected (and same for $P(B)$ and $P(C)$). And then $$ P(\{A=H\}\cap \{B=H\}) = \frac{1}{2}P(\{A=H\}\cap \{B=H\}\mid Z=H) + \frac{1}{2}P(\{A=H\}\cap \{B=H\}\mid Z=T) \\= \frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{4}\frac{3}{4}+ \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{16},$$ so $$ P(A=H\mid B=H) = \frac{P(\{A=H\}\cap \{B=H\})}{P(B=H)} = \frac{5/16}{1/2} = 5/8$$ which is greater than $1/2$ as expected. The exact same calculation would give the same answer for $B=H$ conditional on $C=H$ and $C=H$ conditional on $A=H.$

Answer (score 0):

Your original proposal is essentially impossible.  To simplify writing, let $a=(A=T)$, etc.  Then the first statement is $P(a|b)=0.1$ and $P(a|b')=0.0$.  These can be rewritten as $P(a\cap b)=0.1P(b)$ and $P(a\cap b')=0$.  Since, in general $P(a)=P(a\cap b)+P(a\cap b')$, using $P(a\cap b')=0.0$ we have $P(a\cap b)=P(a)=0.1P(b)$.  Putting this together with the other two statements we get $P(a)=0.1P(b)=0.01P(c)=0.001P(a)$.  This can be true only in the trivial case when $P(a)=P(b)=P(c)=0$.

In your original example you concluded that $P(A=T)=0.0$ is the only thing that makes sense.  You are right.